# negative margins to 'shrink' a div

Tags: css

So, i have a div which i want to take up the entire width of the browser, -40px on each side,

my idea was to have

`width: 100%; and margin: 0 -40px;` however this does not work.

I dont want to use `width: xx%` as i have no control over this.

---

**Update**
Ok got it going at http://jsfiddle.net/ApcLv/

but now my question is:

How do i get this to be centered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap it in a another `<div>` and give the parent `<div>` a `width:100%` property, and the child `<div>` a `margin:40px;` property:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" >
<head >
    <title >Example</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #wrapper {
            width:100%;
        }
        #main {
            margin:40px;
            background-color:red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="main">
        This is a test
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this will give margin not only to left-right but top-bottom also. so it needs margin:0 40px; .But the paint point is good ;)

Answer (score 0):

have a div in a div... the outer div can be 100% wide with a 40px padding and the inner div can be 100% wide too.. which will take up the inner div's width - the 40px padding. :)

Comment: doing this method will result in a width of 100% + 40px as the padding is added to the div, not subtracted.

Answer (score 0):

Simply

```
[..]
<body>
<div style="margin: 40px">Blabla</div>
</body>
[..]
```

..will create a DIV that takes up all available horizontal space, minus 40px on each side.

A block level element always uses all its available horizontal space unless otherwise specified. A div with exactly 40px to each side of the BODY element will thus always be centered. No need for wrappers to achieve this.